# Why use VALUE HIGH-VALUES in 88 Conditionals?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I understand that HIGH-VALUES correspond to the highest in the collating sequence, however I do not understand why it may be a preferred method when using conditionals.

Example:

```
01 StudentRecord.
   88 EndOfStudentFile     VALUE HIGH-VALUES.
   02 StudentID            PIC X(7).
   02 FILLER               PIC X(23).

   ...

   AT END SET EndOfStudentFile TO TRUE
```

Why not simply use VALUE 0 and SET EndOfStudentFile to 1 ?

Whats the advantage of using HIGH-VALUES in these cases?

Appreciate any input on this matter...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditional 88 in your example is for the `StudentRecord`, so it sets/queries that. I *think* that it may be more appropriate to use `VALUE ALL HIGH-VALUES` - as it stands it will set the first byte to `HIGH-VALUE` and then pad the record (with spaces).

`VALUE 0`/`1` would not be possible for that as the record - because it is a group - is alphanumeric, and should not be assigned a numeric value.

... the question "is xyz preferred" is often more a question of style and only rarely "best practice". The commonly good thing is to ensure a consistent use/style so that others reading the code can understand it better.

In this specific case it *could* be used to "store" the information "all students were processed" which then can be queried later via `IF EndOfStudentFile` and if for some reason there is another `START >= StudentID` (I assume that is an `ORGANIZATION INDEXED` file here) on the file it likely will not found "another" record (still possible here, a student with an id containing `ALL HIGH-VALUE` would be found).

Comment: I understand now why I cannot use numerals (88 = only alphanumeric), thank you.

Ok regarding style, but seems a lot easier just using VALUE "Y" then ALL HIGH VALUES (takes more space).

Ok, so you mean I could do: 88 EndOfStudentFile     VALUE "All students were processed" ?

Comment: That would work if `StudentRecord is long enough` (as long as you don't access the numeric fields possibly contained in the record).
But both `Y` and `All students...` would not serve the _possible_ "`START key >= student-id` should not result in more data" purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify '88' levels do not represent real storeage.
They are conditionals which refer to the immediately preceding variable definition.

So:

```
If EndOfStudentFile..
```

is just as shortcut for

```
If StudentRecord is equal to High-Values...
```